# using Google translate service api in Java

Tags: java, google-translate

I am facing difficulty using google translate service api from my java code. For google translate I don not need to use OAuth, so I am simply firing the URI along with the required parameters but getting all sorts of errors like 404 or file not found exception.

```
URL - https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
Parameters - key=**********&q=Please%20translate%20me.&source=en&target=fr
```

I am not able figure what else is required. If anyone of you can guide me or direct me to some example code or blog would be really helpful.

Comment: "Google Translate API is available as a paid service" https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Comment: The Google translate API is a paid service and you have to use OAuth to identify yourself to Google as someone who has paid to use the service.  If you're not using OAuth, it's not going to work.

Comment: @PaulHicks I read that we can either use API key or OAuth so I thought this should work just using api key as it works when I hit this URI using browser. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Because I didn't read far enough down the page :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it working following this blog post. Looks like it doesn't need OAuth to make it work from Java code. Just api key is enough.

http://hayageek.com/google-translate-api-tutorial/#java-example